# Memory allocation and char arrays

Tags: c++, c

I still do not quite understand, what exactly will happen in the situation:

```
int i = 0;
for(i; i <100; i ++)
{
    char some_array[24];
     //...
    strcpy(some_array,"abcdefg");

}
```

Will the `some_array` act as:

`some_array = malloc(24);`

At the beginning of the cycle and
`free(some_array)` at the end of the cycle?

Or those variables are gonna be allocated in the stack, and after the function ends destroyed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`some_array` is local to the *block*, so it's created at the beginning of each iteration of the loop, and destroyed again at the end of each iteration of the loop.

In the case of a simple array, "create" and "destroy" don't mean much. If (in C++) you replace it with (for example) an object that prints something out when it's created and destroyed, you'll see those side effects happen though.

Comment: I understand that! But does that mean that it's gonna be created in the program stack or it's gonna basicaly turn into the dynamic memory allocation like `malloc` call?

Comment: @Vanya: That's up to the implementation, but on a typical implementation it'll be on the stack not the heap/free store.

Comment: basically i'm asking because i want to test what is better, having some statically char array, or allocating the memory each iteration, using malloc, and then free'ying it

Comment: @Vanya: If it's much memory, allocating on the heap might be neccessary to avoid breaking the stack. But always remember that `malloc` and `free` are orders of magnitude more expensive than stack-allocation on just about any implementation.

Comment: @Vanya: You normally want to use automatic allocation unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise. IOW, unless you can point to a specific reason *to* use `malloc`/`free`, you probably don't want to. In C++, you rarely need to use dynamic allocation directly, and on the rare occassion that you do, you probably want to use `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of storing character strings.
1. Creating some space using malloc and then storing the char string
 In this case memory is allocated from heap and will not be freed until you free it explicitly. Here memory is not deallocated even after the scope
2. Creating an array and storing in it
  Here memory is allocated from stack and is freed implicitly after the scope

Comment: There are also constant literals, statically allocated.

Comment: Which way is faster? Assuming that i know i will have the strings no longer than 256 bytes. creating pre-allocated char array at the beginning of the loop like : `char file_name[256];` or allocating and freeying the memory each time, using `file_name = malloc(256); free(file_name);`

Comment: stack memory(array implementation) is faster than heap(malloc allocation). Dynamic allocation takes extra work like moving the pointer to specifies location in heap which is an extra decision making overhead. Stack allocation is fixed size. Secondly, memory allocated from heap needs redirection. I mean we need to move from stack working space to heap space. These issues doesnt matter on higher level though. This speed difference is negligible as a matter of high level programming

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit malloc() or free calls introduced by the example shown.

You can demonstrate that by adding a "free(some_array)" statement within the loop body.  The result will be a compilation error.

The array is - as far as the program is concerned - created at the start of the block and destroyed at the end.  Which means the C programmer must assume it is created and destroyed for every iteration of the loop.

It is up to the compiler as to whether the array is created on the stack - or how it optimises the repeated creation and destruction of the array.  In practice, it often will be created on the stack.

Comment: `free(some_array);` does not cause a compilation error, just undefined behaviour when that statement is encountered at runtime